# on change dropdown change its relative dropdown value according to the first dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple select box like:

```
<select name="new[]" class="form-control" id="new">
```

on change I want to change it's correspond select box value

```
<select name="news[]" class="form-control" id="news">
```

My jQuery code for change value:

```
$('select[name="new[]"]').on('change', function(){
     var v=$(this).val();
  // alert(v);
     $('select[name="news"]').val(v);

 })
```

but in single select it's working fine but when I have multiple select boxes in that case when I am changing the one drop down it's changing all the other drop downs. Can anyone help me related this?

Comment: can you show the connection between the 2 select?

Comment: `but when i have multiple select boxes`  are you using same name for all dropdowns?

Comment: already posted the both select .. both have the country but in different lang values same for both the option

Comment: yes @ashik.....

Comment: you need to use unique names or ids,

Comment: Can you please get someone fluent in English to do this for you? not trying to offend I just can't make any sense of it.

Comment: Will you please show more code to us?

Comment: What's the code having problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from your code everything is working fine but if you use same `name` `arb_country[]` all the select box with that name would be changer to avoid that you should be more specific in the query selector like wrapping the the selects boxes inside a div like this :

```js
$('select[name="eng_country[]"]').on('change', function(){
     var selectedval=$(this).val();
  // alert(selectedval);
     $('.selectboxes select[name="arb_country[]"]').val(selectedval);

 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectboxes">
<select name="eng_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="eng_country">
<option value="1">country 1</option>
<option value="2">country 2</option>
<option value="3">country 3</option>
<option value="4">country 4</option>
</select>

<select name="arb_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="arb_country">
<option value="1">country 1</option>
<option value="2">country 2</option>
<option value="3">country 3</option>
<option value="4">country 4</option>
</select>
</div>
<select name="arb_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="arb_country">
<option value="1">country 1</option>
<option value="2">country 2</option>
<option value="3">country 3</option>
<option value="4">country 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not working cos both the select have different divs its dynamic div

Answer (score 0):

Try with `next()` function of jquery.

***Note :*** You can't have more than one `html` element with same `id` attribute.

```js
$('select[name="eng_country[]"]').on('change', function(){
     var selectedval=$(this).val();
  // alert(selectedval);
     $(this).next('select[name="arb_country[]"]').val(selectedval);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="eng_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="eng_country1">
  <option>Country 1.1</option>
  <option>Country 1.2</option>
  <option>Country 1.3</option>
</select>
<select name="arb_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="arb_country1">
  <option>Country 1.1</option>
  <option>Country 1.2</option>
  <option>Country 1.3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="eng_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="eng_country2">
  <option>Country 2.1</option>
  <option>Country 2.2</option>
  <option>Country 2.3</option>
</select>
<select name="arb_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="arb_country2">
  <option>Country 2.1</option>
  <option>Country 2.2</option>
  <option>Country 2.3</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="eng_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="eng_country3">
  <option>Country 3.1</option>
  <option>Country 3.2</option>
  <option>Country 3.3</option>
</select>
<select name="arb_country[]" class="form-control profile-engform" id="arb_country3">
  <option>Country 3.1</option>
  <option>Country 3.2</option>
  <option>Country 3.3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can i make this id dynamic through jquery loop >??

Comment: are you generating these html with `jquery` loop??